# SWIFT - get update variable from a different class

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire

I wrote a code that gets the balances from different json files and displays your total sum onto a view board using the text field.

I did all this in one swift class. I'm now trying to follow the MVC pattern and make my code cleaner. Before it was easier because i simply refreshed my text field as Alamofire was still getting the JSON requests. Now that I have different files, I'm not able to call my refresh method from the different files whenever the variables changes.

I have tried creating an object of my VC where the refresh file is but that is no help.

In conclusion... how would one go about calling a method in a different swift file?

P.S - Can't share code because of NDA.

Comment: You need to post your code then people can give suggestion. and in this case you can use delegate or block for update view or refresh screen.

Comment: can you post your code so will help